# How to correctly implement Jquery MultiSelect Widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to use Jquery Multiselect in my ASP.NET MVC Razor view. I am using this site as a reference.

http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/filter.htm

I have added the

```
jquery.multiselect.filter.js
```

and

```
 jquery.multiselect.filter.css
```

like it tells you to do. Then I try to place the 1 line they show to create the filter.

```
$("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
```

This dosent work and gives me the following 2 errors on the Developer Tools Console window:

```
jquery.multiselect.filter.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function //In the Javascript file they provide

Index:356 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function//In my Section Scripts
```

Below is my script section at the bottom of my razor view where I am trying to accomplish this.

```
@section scripts
{
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.multiselect.filter.css")"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.multiselect.filter.js")"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
   });
</script>
}
```

Can someone who has used this tool show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the `jQuery UI` library? From what I remember, `widget` is part of it.

Comment: Seems like `multiselect` requires `jQuery-ui` library. You can load `jQuery-ui` before loads the `multiselect` code

Comment: @MelanciaUK I have added jQuery-ui, that got rid of the $.widget is not a function error, it still has $(...).multiselect is not a function error though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line 8 of the source code of `multiselect`, there is

```
 * Depends:
 *   - jQuery UI MultiSelect widget
```

You can load jQuery-ui before loads the multiselect code

Comment: I have added jQuery-ui, that got rid of the $.widget is not a function error, it still has $(...).multiselect is not a function error though

Comment: @Reeggiie Did you add `jQuery` library before `jQuery-ui`?

Comment: Yes I did in my _Layout.cshtml. The order is     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

Comment: @Reeggiie i see where is your error. You added `multiselect.filter` plugin, but did you add `multiselect` widget?

Comment: perfect link, thank you. i was missing jquery.multiselect.js, thank you